# React + Material UI: Static pages do not display

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Background**
I’m building my first react app and building out the basic layout (Header / Footer) and routes to the static pages (About, Contact, etc). My header shows up and when I click the links, the URL in the browser changes (/ -> /about).

**Problem**
The problem is the content within the pages does not show up.

**What I’m doing**
My Index.js imports my App. The App imports from the Header and Routes (defined in a Routes.js file). I have separate files for each page (About.js, Contact.js).

**Question**
Why isn't the body changing when I navigate to `/about` or `/contact`?

**Code**

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./Routes";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <main>
        <Header />
        <Routes />
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
```

Routes.js

```
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Contact.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

export default function Contact() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Header.js

```
import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  makeStyles,
  Button,
  IconButton,
  Drawer,
  Link,
  MenuItem,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import headersData from "../data/header.json";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  header: {
    backgroundColor: "#400CCC",
    paddingRight: "79px",
    paddingLeft: "118px",
    "@media (max-width: 900px)": {
      paddingLeft: 0,
    },
  },
  logo: {
    fontFamily: "Work Sans, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: "#FFFEFE",
    textAlign: "left",
  },
  menuButton: {
    fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 700,
    size: "18px",
    marginLeft: "38px",
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  drawerContainer: {
    padding: "20px 30px",
  },
}));

export default function Header() {
  const { header, logo, menuButton, toolbar, drawerContainer } = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    mobileView: false,
    drawerOpen: false,
  });

  const { mobileView, drawerOpen } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    const setResponsiveness = () => {
      return window.innerWidth < 900
        ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
        : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
    };

    setResponsiveness();

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
  }, []);

  const getDrawerChoices = () => {
    return headersData.map(({ label, href }) => {
      return (
        <Link
          {...{
            component: RouterLink,
            to: href,
            color: "inherit",
            style: { textDecoration: "none" },
            key: label,
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem>{label}</MenuItem>
        </Link>
      );
    });
  };

  const Logo = (
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h1" className={logo}>
      Boats
    </Typography>
  );

  const getMenuButtons = () => {
    return headersData.map(({ label, href }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          {...{
            key: label,
            color: "inherit",
            to: href,
            component: RouterLink,
            className: menuButton,
          }}
        >
          {label}
        </Button>
      );
    });
  };

  const displayDesktop = () => {
    return (
      <Toolbar className={toolbar}>
        {Logo}
        <div>{getMenuButtons()}</div>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  };

  const displayMobile = () => {
    const handleDrawerOpen = () =>
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, drawerOpen: true }));
    const handleDrawerClose = () =>
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, drawerOpen: false }));

    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton
          {...{
            edge: "start",
            color: "inherit",
            "aria-label": "menu",
            "aria-haspopup": "true",
            onClick: handleDrawerOpen,
          }}
        >
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>

        <Drawer
          {...{
            anchor: "left",
            open: drawerOpen,
            onClose: handleDrawerClose,
          }}
        >
          <div className={drawerContainer}>{getDrawerChoices()}</div>
        </Drawer>

        <div>{Logo}</div>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <AppBar className={header}>
        {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
      </AppBar>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you are displaying only `<h1>contact</h1>` then it will be hidden behind the AppBar. Add `position="static"` in AppBar or push your content down

Comment: @Sayog That did it! Why does an element need to have the position defined explicitly? I was assuming it was static by default.

Comment: In material ui AppBar has `position:"absolute"` by default so we have to push the content down or set `position='static`